# Contest proposal: what prize would you want?

Tags: discussion

Our visits have greatly increased, going from ~72 per day to around 1,812 per day. Maybe it's too soon to think they'll stay like this, but even if it seems they're stabilizing we need to do something about it and also about other stats.

Our questions/day are 0.9, the goal is 15 at least each day... One way to encourage people to ask questions is to make a contest. Some questions would be asked and those eligible will nominate a winner. And if there is a winner, there is a prize.

Considering [SE seems to be moving away from prizes that cost money](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129922/176533), what prizes would you propose if there was a contest?

If you propose a prize, do it one per answer, so the others can vote on it. Alternatively you can share your views/opinions on this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a great idea!

One obvious prise would be an X rep for the winning user (whether X is 100 or 1000 is beyond this question).  I'm not sure whether this is doable though.

Comment: From my experience from other sites, it's not that doable... But it's ok, we are just brainstorming for now, so any idea is welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fame is a good thing per se.

We could choose a weeks-best question and weeks-best answer and put it somewhere as a banner with a link to our site.